# Change Android Studio new Project files

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way in Android Studio settings to change the files that are created when a new project is created? Like for example, adding a boilerplate library automatically to new projects, BaseActivity, BaseFragment classes, etc?

Comment: Not in any way that will survive an IDE update. The new-project template is considered to be part of the IDE itself; your changes would get overwritten whenever the tools team decided to ship a new template. Personally, I just don't use the new-project wizard, preferring to copy an existing project and use that as my starting point.

Comment: That's a good alternative. Wouldn't it be possible to save off the changes made to the new project wizard, and then copy them back after any update? Assuming of course that the changes are still valid.

Comment: "Wouldn't it be possible to save off the changes made to the new project wizard, and then copy them back after any update? Assuming of course that the changes are still valid." -- in theory. The fact that this is more or less private means that they could totally change the system around. But, you're welcome to go into `android-studio/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidProject` and play around. Just keep good backups. :-)

Comment: Thanks! If you'll answer the question I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no officially-sanctioned way to do this, and hence no way that will necessarily survive an Android Studio update.

You're welcome to go into `android-studio/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidProject`, where that top-level `android-studio/` directory refers to wherever you have Android Studio installed on your development machine. The contents of that directory consist of some metadata and template files that get used when creating a new project. However:

- Changes that you make here may get overwritten when new Android Studio updates are applied
- There is no guarantee that they will keep using those templates indefinitely